# How much money does it cost to play FIFA 12 online?

Tags: pc, fifa-12

How much money does it cost to play the PC version of FIFA 12 online?

Not regarding Internet or energy costs but only the connection to the server.

Comment: You're going to need to expand your question. What do you mean? FIFA-12 multiplayer require a subscription? Are you talking about internet connection costs? Why do you think it costs to play online (other than the cost of your internet connection)?

Comment: You are right, the question is not well stated. I was only interested in the FIFA-12 server connection. AFAIK if you would want to play FIFA-12 on an x-box it costs money to connect to the x-box live or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing Fifa12 on the PC is free. Unlike for example the Xbox 360 where a subscription to XBox live is needed, the PC version only requires an active internet connection and an original copy of the game.

So if you exclude costs for your connection, power and the original cost of the game online play is free.

Comment: I should add that the PS3 is also free to play online (excluding the cost of the actual game of course), it's only the Xbox Live that charges you to pay to play online